# Sprout Import: No Changes When Updating Entry

Tags: plugin-sproutimport

I'm trying to update existing entries with Sprout Import but when I run the import even though there are no errors the entry's data is not updated. I simplified the JSON script as much as I could and it's still not working:

```
[
    {
    "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutbase\\app\\import\\importers\\elements\\Entry",
    "related": {
      "relatedResources": {
          "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutbase\\app\\import\\importers\\elements\\Entry",
          "params": {
              "slug": "test-import-child",
              "sectionId": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
      "updateElement": {
        "params": {
          "slug": "test-import-parent",
          "sectionId": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I also tried doing it with just a plain text field instead of a relationship field and still didn't get any change.

```
[
  {
    "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutbase\\app\\import\\importers\\elements\\Entry",
    "content": {
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    },
    "settings": {
      "updateElement": {
        "params": {
          "slug": "test-import-parent",
          "sectionId": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to put my `"related"` array inside a `"content"` array:

```
[

  {
    "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutbase\\app\\import\\importers\\elements\\Entry",
    "content": {
      "related": {
        "relatedResources": {
            "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutbase\\app\\import\\importers\\elements\\Entry",
            "params": {
                "slug": "test-import-child",
                "sectionId": 2,
                "siteId": 1
              }
          }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "updateElement": {
        "params": {
          "slug": "test-import-parent",
          "sectionId": 2,
          "siteId": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }

]
```

I also added the `siteId` parameter as a matter of good practice but it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons why it is not updating

1. The fields data should be wrapped with **fields**.
2. If entry is on other site add **siteId** on params
   E.g.

`[
  {
    "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutbase\\app\\import\\importers\\elements\\Entry",
    "content": {
      "title": "Test Import Parent",
      "fields": {
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "updateElement": {
        "params": {
          "slug": "test-import-parent",
          "sectionId": 2,
          "siteId": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`